# pass new file name back to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using some jquery to help upload a file to a php script. Everything is working fine and the file does in fact get uploaded. But during the upload, I have made it so the file gets resized to our needs, with a new unique file name. I'd like to pass that new unique file name back to the jquery and have it display on the page. Right now, it just displays the original image (which is not resized)

Here's the jquery code:

```
    $(function(){
    var btnUpload=$('#upload');
    var status=$('#status');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: 'upload-file.php',
        name: 'uploadfile',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
             if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                // extension is not allowed 
                status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
                return false;
            }
            status.text('Uploading...');
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            //On completion clear the status
            status.text('');
            //Add uploaded file to list
            if(response==="success"){
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
            } else{
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

And then my upload php file looks like this:

```
                $uploaddir = 'uploads'; 
            $file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']); 

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)) { 

                    $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
                    include $path . '/uploads/phmagick.php'; 


                    $temp_file = explode(".", $_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
                    $time = time();

                    $new_file = $time . '.' . $temp_file[1];



                    $p = new phmagick($path . '/uploads/' . $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'], $path . '/uploads/' . $new_file); 

                    $p->convert();


                    $phMagick = new phMagick($path . '/uploads/' . $new_file, $path . '/uploads/' . $new_file); 
                    $phMagick->debug=true; 
                    $phMagick->resize(414,414,true); 


              echo "success"; 
            } else {
                echo "error";
            }
```

Any thoughts on how I can get the new unique file name back, which would be something like: 1397413326.jpg?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo the filename back instead of the word "success".

Comment: I could do that, but how could I make it so that jquery catches the name and displays the new image?

Comment: One solution is to return empty string for errors and change the test:  if(response==="success"){

Comment: Another solution is to return a json object with structured data, so you have different properties on the response object.

Comment: That gave me an idea to reverse the checking process and make sure the name isn't empty, and the changed the file to response - and it works. Thanks!